# using just in sentences/phrases correctly

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage, sentence-structure

a) Terrifying and beautiful, *just like a young girl alone in a Swiss Valley.*

b) Just going to get my car cleaned. (I'm)

Does a) work as a complete sentence, if we view it like b) with an implied subject -: ****It is** **just like a young girl ** or is it a long phrase?

How does it differ from this kind of usage: I left the house, **just as it started to rain.**

Answer (score 1):

Neither a nor b is a complete sentence. Both are missing their subject.  In casual, or spoken English you might accept either by assuming the subject "it is" or "it was".

It differs from the final example, since that sentence has a clear, explicit subject "I".  The phrase starting "just" doesn't even pretend to be a complete sentence.

Comment: Anyway, the first _just_ means _exactly_ and the second means _only_.